# SMS Notification related API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I would like to know if there is any API in windows phone that can hide notifications like, SMS notification. Also I would like to know if we can create private inboxes which would organize the SMS inbox. I already went through the reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516(v=vs.105).aspx. I could not find anything related to requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do either with the current SDK. Developers don't have the ability to change the notifications of other apps or to the SMS inbox.